# Import local module in python

Tags: python-2.7

I just change to new company and they use python to dev. When I see the source from ancestors, I see they use `sys.path` to import local module:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"/folder/")
from folder import module as module
```

I think it is not right. I suggest them to use package like this:

```
import path.to.module as module
```

They ignore my suggest.

Am I right? I google but I don't find any hint for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your method will only work if the module is in your path. Python will add your current working directory to sys.path so it should work for local modules.

However, if you are trying to import a module from another directory, you will likely need to use sys.path.append first

Answer (score 0):

There is an other way is by setting a path to environment variable "PYTHONPATH"